# SevenZipSharp how to extract a specific file out of the archive

Tags: c#, 7zip

in C# when using SevenZipSharp, how can I extract a single specific file? (I don't want to extract all the archive).

Answer (score 1):

```
public void ExtractFile(
    string fileName,
    Stream stream
)
```

Does this help ?

Comment: mm thanks, I tried to do it with FileStream something like this:

SevenZipExtractor extractor = new SevenZipExtractor(zipFileLocation, ZIP_PASSWORD);
Stream st = new FileStream(zipFileLocation,FileMode.Open);                       
extractor.ExtractFile(0,st);


though there isn't any error, I don't see that the file was extracted anyware...
How to define its destination (I don't see any function..)?
maybe I don't use the right Stream object?

Comment: The second argument is described as "The stream where the file is to be unpacked." Not sure if this is needed, but are you closing the stream ?

Comment: you are right.
the stream is the target, and I didn't close it.
now it works, Thanks!